# Set Binding Value For DateTimePicker

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding

I have an EF Entity named Employee. It has a Nullable DateTime Property TerminationDate.

```
[DisplayName("Termination Date")]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:d}")]
public DateTime? TerminationDate { get; set; }
```

In my WinForm I have a DateTimePicker I want to Bind to this property.

```
Binding nullBinding = new Binding(
    propertyName: "Value", 
    dataSource: bs, 
    dataMember: "TerminationDate",
    formattingEnabled: true, 
    dataSourceUpdateMode: DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged,
    nullValue: null
    );
TerminationDateTimePicker.DataBindings.Add(nullBinding);
```

All my other bindings work (But the Dates were not nullable):

```
UsernameTextBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", bs, "Username", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
HireDateTimePicker.DataBindings.Add("Value", bs, "HireDate", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
```

The Termination Date is showing Today's Date when it should be null or empty. Any help would be appreciated.