# Failure binding value of DateTimePicker to DateTime property

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I have an object `myObj` with `DateTime` property `myDate` as well as a `DateTimePicker` control `myDatePicker` in my form.  When I attempt to bind the value of the latter to the former, the following exception is thrown:

```
Exception has occurred: CLR/System.ArgumentException
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll: 'Cannot bind to the property or column myDate on the DataSource.'
```

The relevant code setting up the control:

```
myDatePicker = new DateTimePicker();
// ... (set control position, size, etc.)
myDatePicker.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Short;
myDatePicker.DataBindings.Add("Value", myObj, "myDate");
```

And the relevant part of the class definition:

```
public class myClass : myOtherClass
{
    public DateTime myDate;
    // ...
    
    public myClass()
    {
        // ...
        myDate = DateTime.Today;
    }
}
```

This is exactly how I set up the bindings on every other control on the form (all text boxes) and those all work fine.

I've tried creating a test property in the form and binding to that and I get the same error.  I have also tried binding to the `Date` property of `myObj.myDate` (via `myDatePicker.DataBindings.Add("Value", myObj.myDate, "Date")`), which avoids the error but since `DateTime.Date` has no setter the binding only works one way.

I know this is something simple but I haven't found any other solutions here that seem to address my issue.  All the other questions I found here on binding a `DateTimePicker` seem to be about the binding not working in some way other than straight up throwing an exception like I am experiencing.  ([This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31415253/set-binding-value-for-datetimepicker) may be the same issue but does not give enough information about the failure to tell, and it is 7 years old with no answers.)

Comment: Can you show how your object is defined? That doesn't look like the exception you get when, e.g., the DateTime is `null` (which *could* be solved adding `, true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged` to the Binding, so the null value is formatted as DateTime.Now). What is the value of `myDate` set to? Are you binding this class(?) object to anything else?

Comment: @Jimi The class constructor sets the property to today and it isn't modified anywhere other than here at this point (can't `DateTime` not be `null` at all?).  I also don't think it has anything to do with the class because as I said I tried making a `DateTime` property in the form and binding it to the control and it gave the same error.  I have also tried using the overload you suggest to enable the formatting and update mode to no avail.  The class object does have several other string properties which are bound just fine to text box controls on the form.

Comment: Where's the Property? I can only see a Field there (`DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged` was a hint).

Comment: @Jimi wow that was it, a simple typo of forgetting to make it a property.  Not sure how I missed that in several hours of tearing my hair out staring at this error.